# Is there a framework for writing GUI editor in C#?

Tags: c#, frameworks

Is there a framework for writing GUI editor in C#?
I just want to write an application with a winform which can move,resize image on it.
if there's a framework that would be great.
some sample code is also ok

Comment: What do you mean by GUI editor?

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for a layout manager.

Comment: actually, i want to make a GUI editor for a game,but i don't want to write it from scratch.so, if there is a 'framework' for doing that, that would be great

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio has a built in designer for winforms and webforms. [Here](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Designing_Forms_in_Visual_Studio) is an article explaining how to use the designer for winforms.

For WPF, if not using Visual Studio 2010 you can use expression blend studio.

Comment: I thought Visual Studio 2010 had a WPF designer also.

Comment: As I understand the OP he wants his application to work similar to the forms designer.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at mono static for reference.